# How to create a package in java

Tags: java, package

How can one create a package in Java:

In a book i read its :

```
package package_name

public class whatever{}
.
.
.
```

But shouldn't this be enclosed in parenthesis such as :

```
package package_name
{
public class whatever{}
.
.
.
}
```

Just a minor confusion. Can anyone give me an example of the correct syntax?

Comment: What makes you think it should be second one rather than first even if the book says first is correct? are you confusing it with C++ [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) or [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)'s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for creating package

```
package package_name;

public class Whatever {

}
```

You can find more useful info [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html).

Answer (score 1):

[When creating a package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html), you should choose a name for the package and put a package statement with that name at the top of every source file that contains the classes, interfaces, enumerations, and annotation types that you want to include in the package.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

```
Example :

package illustration;  <------------

import java.awt.*;

public class Drawing {
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Your example shows an import statement, not a package declaration.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ahh.. my confusion.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Package is created as follows

**package package_Name;**

This package name has to be the first statement in the file.Once you declare package name start defining methods or classes or interfaces in it.

If this package you have to use in your any java file then write

**import package_Name;**

so that all the methods defined in the package will be accessible in java file.

Answer (score 0):

No parenthesies. Package is nothing else then just a folder or set of folders. For example, if you create package named: `utils`, new folder will be created in your source folder. If you create package named `org.utils`, two folders will be created in your source folder. `org` and `utils` which will be inside of `org` folder. Also, every next package which starts with `org.` (for example `org.ui`) will be just a new folder created in `org` folder. So your folder hierarchy will look like this:

```
org--
    |
    utils
    |
    ui
```